# Automated Hotfix Release with Semantic Versioning based off of Master Branch

Tags: python, git, automation, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a Python script that lives in my CI pipeline that is responsible for publishing branches and tags, publishing AAR's to our Maven Artifactory, uploading Javadoc, etc.

We used to follow a modified version of Git Flow where we would publish off of either a "support/" branch (for Long Term Support of a Minor Product Version, such as 'support/5.10') or a "release/" branch (for release regression testing.

My script largely relied upon the Git Branch name in order to determine Major/Minor/Patch version bumps.

Now, we are dropping the support branches and moving to a more vanilla Git Flow workflow where we will do HotFixes solely off of Master (well, we will still have release branches, but that problem is solved...)

However, I can't figure out a way to safely determine the patch version off of the Master branch, as it obviously has no identifying characteristics in it's name that we can scrub (I always felt a bit uneasy about the method we are using, but... it worked).

I can access the tags and always bump the highest one, but that's sketchy.

I can input a target version, but that gets in the way of CI and would force us to run this script manually.

Any other thoughts on how to approach this? Anyone already solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I tend to follow the `pypi` standard for representing versions. Place a `setup.py` file in the root of your repo which contains the version information, along with instructions for getting it to work with `pypi`.

[For example:](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html)

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

# Utility function to read the README file.
# Used for the long_description.  It's nice, because now 1) we have a top level
# README file and 2) it's easier to type in the README file than to put a raw
# string in below ...
def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(
    name = "an_example_pypi_project",
    version = "0.0.4",
    author = "Andrew Carter",
    author_email = "andrewjcarter@gmail.com",
    description = ("An demonstration of how to create, document, and publish "
                                   "to the cheese shop a5 pypi.org."),
    license = "BSD",
    keywords = "example documentation tutorial",
    url = "http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project",
    packages=['an_example_pypi_project', 'tests'],
    long_description=read('README'),
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Topic :: Utilities",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
    ],
)
```

Of course you don't need to adhere to this exactly if you aren't using pypi. The takeaway is that you should represent the version in a file which can be read and handled easily.

Comment: this makes sense, but imho it still has the problem of when/how to update that semantic version... i still see a manual portion of the process...

Comment: It's unlikely you are going to get to a point where you don't have some manual interaction with the numbers in the version field. You would have to rigidly follow some behavior that your system can detect in order to automatically increment the value. For example, only merging into master when a MAJOR change is made. Encoding semantic versioning in your branching process itself is obviously a bad idea. It's a lot easier to increment the values yourself.